# jquery newbie question

Tags: jquery

I need your help creating a jquery function for checkboxes when these are disabled, pretty much I want to do something like if the input has attribute disable apply css to the label next to it, if not do nothing. Thanks in advance for your help.

The html looks something like this:

```
<div class="add-filters">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="checkbox" id="filter" name="filter" disabled="disabled" />
       <label for="filter">Filter</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ozzy, if you are concerned about performance, you should consider a solution that does not utilize a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('disabled')) {
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('newClassName');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a bit too loopy for my taste.  ;)

Comment: @Stephen - Your answer looks good. I think mine is in the case that there's more than just checkbox type inputs and in case the label isn't immediately after the input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS3 `:disabled` pseudo-class and the next adjacent sibling selector `+`:

```
$("input:disabled + label").css(/* ... */);
```

This will also work without the use of JavaScript in browsers that support CSS3:

```
input:disabled + label {
    color: silver;
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g76U4/**

Comment: @Stephen, thanks.  Yours is also a good solution, much more compact than the accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Way easier to read:

```
$('input:checkbox:disabled').next().css({color:'#000'}); // use your own styles.
```

or with a class:

```
$('input:checkbox:disabled').next().addClass('yourclass');
```

http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

Or if your DOM changes, you could do this:

```
$('input:checkbox:disabled').siblings('label:first').addClass('yourclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("input[disabled], textarea[disabled]").each(function() {
    $(this).next('label').css('color','#0000FF');
  });
});
```

Comment: I think a loop is a bit much.

Comment: jQuery internally loops through the DOM elements returned by the selector anyway.  Matter of preference.

Comment: Good point!  I was almost inclined to agree, but your loop introduces a new jQuery object on each iteration `$(this)`.  So it's a little more than a matter of preference.  ;)

Comment: Ok, even still.  Realistically, you aren't going to see any noticeable performance hit unless you have LOTS of disabled inputs on your page. I still say its a matter of preference.